# Blank page when editing or creating new page (with block editor) and in the widgets pages WP, probably link with the wp.blocks

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem, when I try to open any page (to edit or creating) in the block editor, the page won't load and stay white.
When I put this code in the wp-config.php I can edit in a normal way but all layouts from the site broke.

`define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`

If I use the classic layout to edit or create.

I believe that the problem is with a plugin that I use to edit my pages called, **Gutentor - Gutenberg Blocks - Page Builder for Gutenberg Editor**.

This is the errors that appearing in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setCategories')
    at post.php?post=2329&action=edit:2038
block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__unstableGetBlockProps')
    at Module.tr0p (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:12)
    at n (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:2)
    at wp.blockEditor.//Lo (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:2)
    at block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:2
block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BlockIcon')
    at Module.K51g (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:23)
    at o (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2)
    at wp.blockLibrary.1CF3 (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2)
    at block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2
editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'store')
    at Module.PLxR (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:7)
    at n (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:2)
    at wp.editor.16Al (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:2)
    at editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:2
wp-modula-gutenberg.js?ver=2.5.5:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MediaUpload')
    at Module.<anonymous> (wp-modula-gutenberg.js?ver=2.5.5:1)
    at a (wp-modula-gutenberg.js?ver=2.5.5:1)
    at wp-modula-gutenberg.js?ver=2.5.5:1
    at wp-modula-gutenberg.js?ver=2.5.5:1
blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BlockPreview')
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=1.1.2:1)
formselector.min.js?ver=1.7.0:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerBlockType')
    at Object.1 (formselector.min.js?ver=1.7.0:1)
    at c (formselector.min.js?ver=1.7.0:1)
    at o (formselector.min.js?ver=1.7.0:1)
    at formselector.min.js?ver=1.7.0:1
blocks-deactivate.min.js?ver=3.1.5:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unregisterBlockType')
    at Object.2 (blocks-deactivate.min.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at b (blocks-deactivate.min.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at blocks-deactivate.min.js?ver=3.1.5:1
    at blocks-deactivate.min.js?ver=3.1.5:1
blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerBlockType')
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at t (blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1)
    at blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1
    at blocks.build.js?ver=3.1.5:1
edit-post.min.js?ver=3656613c515e40e95a15114467097b39:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerCoreBlocks')
    at Module.el (edit-post.min.js?ver=3656613c515e40e95a15114467097b39:49)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (post.php?post=2329&action=edit:2222)
```

**UPDATE**

The page widgets have the same issue.

I think that the source of the problem is the **wp.blocks**.

1 - Even in the troubleshoot mode I have the issue (no plugins and no theme).

2 - In all my browser (Opera mini, google chrome, firefox, edge) I gave the issue

3 - DNS flush is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, "fa-solid-900.woff2" this file was corrupeted....

I did a complet hex sum check of all files end version of then on the web, end the only one with a diference was the "fa-solid-900.woff2", so I just dowloaded and uploaded this file.